# Php Array Count to run script run for each reply till 3rd reply and not more than that

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have a Forum in which adscript is displayed after every reply

```
<?php if( count( $replies ) <= 3 ){ ?>

---- script ----

<?php } ?>
```

Earlier there was a clause that there could be maximum 3 replies per Forum post - but now that clause is changed and there are 5, 7 or 10 replies even

I want to modify code so EVEN If there are more than 3 replies - then script should run after each reply till 1st 3 replies and not from 4th reply onwards

I believe an array is to used likely

```
<?php
$replyCount = 0;
foreach( $replies as $reply )
{
$replyCount++;
$replyNumber = array(1, 2, 3);

if (in_array($replyCount, $replyNumber)) {
echo "script";
}
?>
```

But - what the above script is doing is that

> Its displaying the script in all replies
>
> Its displaying script 3 times after each reply

Can some one help and advise in modification so that

> Script should run once after each reply
>
> Script should run till 3rd reply and not more than that

Pls help and advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `break;` after `echo 'script'`.

You said:

> Its displaying the script in all replies
>    Its displaying script 3 times
>   after each reply

That's because your for loop is doing 3 iterations since on the first iteration `replyCount` gets value of 1, is 1 in the array? yes.
Second iteration `replyCount` gets value of 2 etc etc.

EDIT:
Answer to your comments:

```
<?php 
/* CASE Where number of replies is 3 or less. */
/* Prints "script" 1 extra time than count($replies) */
$counter = 0;
if(count($replies) <= 3) {
    foreach($replies as $reply) {
        if(count($replies) == $counter) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            echo "script";
        }
        $counter++;
    }
}
/* CASE Where number of replies is 4 or more print script 3 times. */
else {
    echo 'script' . '<br />';
    echo 'script' . '<br />';
    echo 'script' . '<br />';
}
?>
```

Please read the current code posted here and then see the cases:

**Case 1:** `count($replies) = 0`

> foreach loop starts
>   first `IF` fires, nothing happens

**Case 2:**
`count($replies) = 1`

> foreach loop starts
>   go into `else`
>   print script
>   `$counter` is now 1
>   `count($replies) == $counter`
>   stop loop
>   result is that we have 'script' printed 1 time.

**Case 3:** `count($replies) = 2`

> foreach loop starts
>   go into `else`
>   print script
>   `$counter` is now 1
>   go into `else`
>   print script
>   `$counter` is now 2
>   `count($replies) == $counter`
>   stop loop
>   result is that we have 'script' printed 2 times.

**Case 4:** `count($replies) = 3`

> foreach loop starts
>   go into `else`
>   print script
>   `$counter` is now 1
>   go into `else`
>   print script
>   `$counter` is now 2
>   go into `else`
>   print script
>   `$counter` is now 3
>   `count($replies) == $counter`
>   stop loop
>   result is that we have 'script' printed 2 times.

**Case 5:** `count($replies) > 3`

> result is that we have 'script' printed 3 times.

These are the results if you go over the iterations of this `foreach` loop.

Comment: @ Odedta - Thanks - it works by removing in loop and is showing once after each reply. But - how to also restrict so that it shows after each reply till 3rd reply only. As of now the script showing after all the replies.

Comment: What does `count( $replies )` returns?

Comment: It returns number of replies . If post has 5 replies - it will return 5. If post has 2 replies - it will return 2

Comment: Why do you define this array `$replyNumber = array(1, 2, 3);` inside the foreach loop? are those numbers random or they are supposed to be inside that array? please explain again what you want to achieve, there might be better code for this.

Comment: Hello - i want to achieve in - wherein a script should run in after 1st reply if total count of replies is 1. Script should run in after 1st and 2nd reply if count of replies is 2. To run in after 1st, 2nd and 3rd reply - if count is 3 and from then if count is 4 or more - script should only run in after 1st, 2nd and 3rd reply.

Comment: I have revised my answer.

Comment: Hello Odedta, Thanks for taking time. But the code is again echoing in script 3 times after each reply. Also - in cases where reply is more than 3 - still the script is echoed in all the replies. Say - there are 7 replies - the script is echoed in all 7 replies

Comment: Change `if(count($replies) == $counter)` to `if((count($replies) - 1) == $counter)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82058/discussion-between-odedta-and-ruchika).

Comment: Though logic given is correct, but somehow facing in the issue as originally mentioned. Looks like am messing with something else. Still - basis your time and effort to put an explaination - accepting it as good answer